# Error al hacer insert a columna sin valor predeterminado

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

buenas tengo dos tablas una usuario y otra tipo de usuario las cuales están relacionadas quisiera guardar los datos en java mysql netbeans que al introducir los datos en usuario se me carguen en tipo de usuario para dar el nivel o el privilegio en el sistema hice un ensayo porque de versad soy nuevo en esto y este es parte del proyecto de la universidad, realice una sentencia pero me dio los siguiente esta es la sentencia:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement ap=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tipo_usuario(regente,almacenista,auxiliar) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    ap.setInt(1, cbtipo_usuario.getSelectedIndex());
    ap.setInt(2, cbtipo_usuario.getSelectedIndex());
    ap.setInt(3, cbtipo_usuario.getSelectedIndex());
    ap.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement pps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,contraseña,nombre,apellido,nacio,cedula,telefono,sexo,direccion,tipo_usuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    pps.setString(1, txtusu.getText());
    pps.setString(2, contra.getText().toString());
    pps.setString(3, txtnombre.getText());
    pps.setString(4, txtapellido.getText());
    pps.setString(5, cbnacion.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pps.setString(6, txtcedul.getText());
    pps.setString(7, cbsexo.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pps.setString(8, cbope.getSelectedItem().toString() + "" + txttelf.getText());
    pps.setString(9, txtdireccion.getText());
    pps.setInt(10, cbtipo_usuario.getSelectedIndex());

    pps.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DATOS REGISTRADOS");
```

pero al correr me da el siguiente error: Error aquí: java.sql.SQLException: El campo 'tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario' no tiene un valor predeterminado

como lo puedo arreglar o hacerlo gracias a la persona que me pueda ayudar mil gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor mejore su redacción, si esta en la universidad me da a pensar que puede mejorarlo, por ejemplo la siguiente sección: *realice una sentencia pero me dio los siguiente esta es la sentencia:*, que sentido tiene.

Comment: Ademas mejore el titulo, es muy ambiguo, ?cuantas preguntas podrian usar este titulo? respuestas: todas las preguntas de java, por favor lea las reglas de [ask]

Comment: Debes incluir la columna `tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` a tu `INSERT` a la tabla `usuario`.

Answer (score 0):

Estan mal definidos los campos en tu base de datos. Como los tenes definidos en este momento, tenes que pasarle el valor al campo, cosa que no estas haciendo.

Supongo que querias que idtipo_usuario fuera un autonumerico, por lo tanto tenias que setear el campo con el flag AUTO_INCREMENT, para que solo tomara un valor.

Tu create deberia haber sido algo asi:

```
CREATE TABLE tipo_usuario(
     idtipo_usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ....
);
```

Si no, deberias pasarle un valor al hacer el insert, pero no se si es lo que querias.